# How to save created excel instance to client's disk with save as dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop, excel-interop, save-as

In a project when user click a button, some data is gotten and written to an excel instance by interop library.

Now, I want that: When excel instance get all data, a save as dialog box muste be open and save this excel instance to user specified path.

Is there a way to do it?

Edit:

My code to get data to excel is here:

```
Public Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal outputPath As String)
    ' Create the Excel Application object
    Dim excelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass

    ' Create a new Excel Workbook
    Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)

    Dim excelSheet As Excel.Worksheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    excelApp.Visible = True
    ' Copy each DataTable as a new Sheet
    'sheetIndex += 1

    '' Create a new Sheet
    'excelSheet = CType( _
    '    excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add(excelWorkbook.Sheets(sheetIndex), _
    '    Type.Missing, 1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

    excelSheet.Name = "Bayi"

    ' Copy the column names (cell-by-cell)
    For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        excelSheet.Cells(1, col + 1) = dt.Columns(col).ColumnName
    Next

    CType(excelSheet.Rows(1, Type.Missing), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Font.Bold = True

    ' Copy the values (cell-by-cell)
    For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        For row = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            excelSheet.Cells(row + 2, col + 1) = dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
        Next
    Next

    excelSheet = Nothing

    ' Save and Close the Workbook
    excelWorkbook.SaveAs(outputPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, _
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, _
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

    excelWorkbook.Close(True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

    excelWorkbook = Nothing

    ' Release the Application object
    excelApp.Quit()
    excelApp = Nothing

    ' Collect the unreferenced objects
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using Excel on the server? **Don't**.

Comment: My code is above. What's wrong about it?

Comment: SLaks@1+ ! I could not agree more!

Comment: Bu I said why,  and what should it done? Please give your example about it.

Comment: Se my answar below, Doing this on server true?! Since this is subject are tagged "ASP.NET"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, that this is what you want, but if you want to let a user download an excel file, that you've created on the server side, then just write the content of the excel file to the Response, set the correct mime type - and there you go! 
P.S. Don't forget to clear the currently generated response.

Comment: It's what I want. Thank you Hassan.

Answer (score 1):

If u try to add it to the client from a webserver, there is no way that case. Without getting you to install a flash / silverlight on the client or something similar, to go beyond the security of the browser client software.

**Updated:**
Her is "[A quick look at Silverlight 3: Save File Dialog](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/03/18/a-quick-look-at-silverlight-3-save-file-dialog.aspx)"
And [How to read and write files in JavaScript](http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm)

Comment: Ok, can you give me some link or resource about technic which you advice?

Comment: do you say, it can't be solved with asp.net or javascript? Thats's senseless

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm looking to your second link now.

Comment: Yes, But it is possible with JavaScript **if the user have installed ActiveX** See Update!